# Anyway to keep the height of a layout as wrap content, but not let it exceed a certain height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-layoutparams

I have a `ScrollView` that contains a `TextView` which is fetched dynamically from a data base. If the text is small in length, I want my `ScrollView` `layout_height` to wrap content, however if the text length is big, I want the `ScrollView` `layout_height` to be fixed to a certain value (such as 200dp). Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Use `android:maxHeight` to set the maximum height that you want the `ScrollView` to be.

Comment: I have set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:maxHeight= "100dp"` to my `ScrollView`, but it is not working

Comment: We have no way to know what "it is not working" means, sorry.

Comment: The android:maxHeight for ScrollView is not working with android:layout_height = "wrap_content". If the text content in the ScrollView exceeds the maxHeight, it does not limit it. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: I cannot answer that. You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve]. Show us the complete layout, including the `ScrollView` and the `TextView`, and perhaps we may see something.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're looking for

```
 android:minHeight="12dp" 
 android:maxHeight="200dp"
```

just some example values, you don't have to use both, but you can set `maxHeight` to a certain value so that the view never exceeds those values and perhaps `minHeight` so that it doesn't collapse entirely, unless you want that, in which case just remove `minHeight`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code into LinearLayout with wrap_content option and on inner structure you can set android:layout_weight="1"